# I am getting a scope error and uninitialized error with same variable

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
  int a, b, num, y;
  cin >> num;
  switch (num){
    case 1: soi_cout();
      cin >> num;
      if(num == 1){
        ab_cout();
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++){
          y += y1(i);
          return 0;
        }

        return 0;
      }
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I define y as an int with this code I get the error

> 'y' may be used uninitialized in this function

```
int main(){
  int a, b, num;
  cin >> num;
  switch (num){
    case 1: soi_cout();
      cin >> num;
      if(num == 1){
        ab_cout();
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++){
          y += y1(i);
          return 0;
        }

        return 0;
      }
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Then when I don't declare y as a variable I get this error:

> 'Y is not defined in this scope'

Please help. I am going crazy over this.

Comment: You need to declare it **and** initialize it. It's not either/or.

Comment: Removing line number may help other copy and execute easily.

Comment: @JonathanPotter how do I do both of those?

Comment: `int y=0;` is one way.

Comment: Btw @SamR. it seems that you misunderstand `return 0;`. Your program will exit when it hits the first line with this statement.

Answer (score 1):

First order of business, you have to make something to use it, so you need to declare variable. This will fix your second error.

```
int main(){
  int a, b, num;
  int y; // THIS FIXES SECOND ERROR YOU HAVE
  y = 0; // THIS FIXES FIRST ERROR YOU HAVE

  cin >> num;
  switch (num){
    case 1: soi_cout();
      cin >> num;
      if(num == 1){
        ab_cout();
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++){
          y += y1(i);
          return 0;
        }

        return 0;
      }
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

> 'y' may be used uninitialized in this function

This is just a warning and you can ignore it but it is not advisable, simply do

```
int y = 0
```

instead of

```
int y;
```

and your problem is solved.

Comment: Ignoring the warning is bad advice, it is there for a reason. In this case OP's code would result in `y` containing a "garbage" value.

Comment: I did not say you should ;) Thank you @MatthäusBrandl for suggestion I fixed my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what this 'y' for?You don't output anything with this variable.....

But just for your question,like what the error 75 told you,you should initialize this variable.
For example:

```
63 int main(){
 64     int a, b, num, y;
 65     cin >> num;
 66 switch (num){
 67
 68     case 1: soi_cout();
 69             cin >> num;
 70                     if(num == 1){
 71                         ab_cout();
 72                         cin >> a;
 73                         cin >> b;
                            y = 0;  //or any number you want to initialize
 74                         for(int i=a; i<=b; i++){
 75                         y += y1(i);//you can't just declare this 'y' because you used it in there
 76                         return 0;
 77                         }
 78
 79                         return 0;
 80                     }
 81                     return 0;
 82                 }
 83
 84
 85 return 0;
 86 }
```